# Efficient long multiplication with double word result

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to optimize the multiplication code of a [31.32 fixed-point math library written in C#](https://github.com/asik/FixedMath.Net).

The (incorrect) pseudo code is:
`long result = (a * b) >> 32;`

The problem of course is the potential overflow of `a * b` before being shifted down. Even if `(a * b) >> 32` (the end result of the multiplication) is in the value range of `long`, the intermediate value `a * b` may not be.

The usual solution is to split `a` and `b` into a low and high part each and perform the shift operation on the high parts before the multiplication step. This avoids the overflow of the intermediate value, but makes the code rather more complicated:

```
var xl = x.m_rawValue;
var yl = y.m_rawValue;

var xlo = (ulong)(xl & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF);
var xhi = xl >> FRACTIONAL_PLACES;
var ylo = (ulong)(yl & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF);
var yhi = yl >> FRACTIONAL_PLACES;

var lolo = xlo * ylo;
var lohi = (long)xlo * yhi;
var hilo = xhi * (long)ylo;
var hihi = xhi * yhi;

var loResult = lolo >> FRACTIONAL_PLACES;
var midResult1 = lohi;
var midResult2 = hilo;
var hiResult = hihi << FRACTIONAL_PLACES;

var sum = (long)loResult + midResult1 + midResult2 + hiResult;
```

The resulting machine code is similarly complex.

The x86 `imul` instruction can return a double word result in two registers in a single instruction, but I have no idea how to write C# code that the compiler could optimize to use this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code sample is very hard to understand for us mere mortals. Could you please either clarify it or leave it out if it's not important for the question? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve (I'm struggling to understand why `long` multiplication is not sufficient to be specific). Obviously you cannot write assembly in C# to have `imul` with qword result so we would need a bigger picture to propose a solution that is performant.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek: We represent a fixed-point number as two 32 bit unsigned integers, stuffed into a `long`. The high 32 bit integer represents the integer part. The low 32 bit integer represents the fractional part.  To multiply two of them together, we split them up into the high and low parts, and then the arithmetic is straightforward.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek: If n is 2 to the 32, then a pair of ints `a, b` represents the value `a + b/n`.  So if we have `(a+b/n)*(c+d/n)` what computations must you do to figure out the high and low ints of the product?

Comment: If you 1) defined `FRACTIONAL_PLACES` and 2) Replaced `x1`/`y1` with a hardcoded value, you would have a *Complete* example.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Answer (score 0):

Core 3.0 added support for that imul x64 CPU instruction you were looking for:

```
ulong lo64Bits;
ulong hi64Bits= System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86.Bmi2.X64.MultiplyNoFlags(a, b, &lo);
```

(of course it is limited to x86 arch)

Answer (score -4):

Floating point number always have imprecision. [It is in their nature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0). Trying to use Floats without Floating point inprecision or any integral type without overflows is like trying to do flight without air.

The solutions are to either use really large Integers instead (displaying the Decimal marker only during output) or a fixed width Decimal type (wich are Integers behind the scenes). If you really a really big Integer, there is the [BigInteger Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx#Remarks). It's upper limit is "whatever the GC can allocate" and it can run into a OOM Exception.

As for speed, there are two things to consider:

1. [The Speed Rant](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)
2. By the nature of the .NET Framework, you only have that much control over the speed. Whenever the GC decides to collect, you will have all threads halted and get intermittend stalls. While you can make it effective, you can never make a Realtime Application (with guaranteed response times) in .NET. If that was your goal, .NET was the wrong direction.

Comment: The OP is not talking about floating point numbers. Also, having speed as a goal for a math library developer seems very legitimate. Using `decimal` etc. may be insufficient for such case (while very appropriate for other usages though). Questioning merits of such library is on point though. But there are also games developed using C# and new language features such as `ref` returns seem to be pointing in this direction as well.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek: BigInt is the only thing that can store arbitrarily large numbers. And it is inmutable, so you will not get around assigning a lot of those. The kind of speed and efficiency he wants might simply not be possible in a garbage collected runtime where you have to jump through hoops to even use naked pointers. If this was native C++ it would be a whole lot easier.

Comment: As already suggested in the comments above, I do not need arbitrary precision or range - 64 bits are fine, but 32 are not enough, otherwise I would not have this issue.

The use case behind this question is a physics engine, which does millions of these multiplications per second, so performance really does matter here.

Comment: This isn't a floating point operation in the first place; this is fixed point. And I don't see what my rant has to do with the problem; the original poster is not posting two pieces of code and asking "which is faster?" -- that's the situation my rant was intended to address. Optimizing inner loop operations like multiplications is a perfectly reasonable thing to look into if you have trillions of multiplications to do.

Comment: suggested reading: [The 'premature optimization is evil' myth](http://joeduffyblog.com/2010/09/06/the-premature-optimization-is-evil-myth/).

Comment: @EricLippert: That is why I mentioned the other side: This level of performance might be impossible in .NET. Top performance usually needs a environment where less checks are in place. I learned in native C++ and while I understand the speed advantage of using naked pointers even for array access (no out of bounds checks), in 99% of all cases I would not want to miss the advantages of a Garbage Collector. But this might just be the 1% https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/286d8c7f-87ca-46b9-9608-2b559d7dc79f/garbage-collection-pros-and-limits?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @sAm_vdP: It looks like .NET simply does not have a float type with the proper range. That is another case where you have to go the "really large inteteger" route. Or uses a different, less managed language that has such a type/allows you to make such a type effectively. I advise against "crossing into unmanaged" code whenever I see it, but some cases are simply unavoidable. This might just be one of them.

Comment: @TnTinMn: Anything is stupid if overdone. The developers of "foolproof" designs and advise underestiamte the ability of the fools. I did not gave any advise with a "foolproof" label nor would I link anything like that. The performance rant was a possible answer based on the incomplete information given back then. The actuall case passed check 2: He really needs to know that answer!